# Should dependencies be deleted from disk automatically after install/update with Composer?

Tags: php, dependency-management, composer-php

After removing a dependency from composer.json and running install or update, should I expect the files to be removed automatically from disk?

I had to remove them manually, not sure if I am supposed to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running a composer **update** will remove packages you removed from your composer.json.

Since **install** uses *composer.lock* instead of *composer.json* it will **not** remove packages removed from your *composer.json*. However, you should get a message that your lock file is out of sync with your *composer.json* and you should run an update.