# Symfony2 having an issue with phpexcel and service_xls5

Tags: php, symfony, service, phpexcel

Symfony2 having problem with  $excelService = $this->get('xls.service_xls5');

The problem shown is

```
You have requested a non-existent service "xls.service_xls5".
500 Internal Server Error - ServiceNotFoundException
```

Any idea how  to solve this?

By the way, this is my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "apy/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": ">=1.0.4",
    "mbence/opentbs-bundle": "dev-master",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"
}
```

But I can't install phpoffice/phpexcel that has been my last try..

---

Modification on 25/06/2014

After the help of Splendonia, I was able to install/update in a correct way my luiggioBundle and realize that now It has a new API. Then I ran the example that is in LuiggioBundle in Github documentation and all worked just fine.

```
namespace YOURNAME\YOURBUNDLE\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        // ask the service for a Excel5
       $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();

       $phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator("liuggio")
           ->setLastModifiedBy("Giulio De Donato")
           ->setTitle("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
           ->setSubject("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
           ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2005 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
           ->setKeywords("office 2005 openxml php")
           ->setCategory("Test result file");
       $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
           ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
           ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!');
       $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
       // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
       $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        // create the writer
        $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
        // create the response
        $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
        // adding headers
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=stream-file.xls');
        $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');

        return $response;        
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle?

Comment: I think so. I edited the post so now you can see my composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, When you're adding  `"liuggio/excelbundle": ">=1.0.4"`, to your composer.json, it should automatically dowload dependencies when you run `composer install` or `composer update`. In my case, my composer.json has this:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "~2.0"
    }
```

always, after adding new bundles to your composer.json, you should run composer update to add the new dependencies, doing this:

```
php composer.phar update
```

After the process is completed, you need to register the bundle in **app/AppKernel.php** file like this...

```
$bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),
    );
```

Note: in my case I need to open a file so, In my Controller I need to add **use PHPExcel_IOFactory;** at the beginning.

```
$readerObject = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$phpExcelObject = $readerObject->load('path/to/file. '.xls');
```

To write new excel files do:

```
$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();
$phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator('Me')
                                    ->setLastModifiedBy('Me')
                                    ->setTitle("General Overview");
$phpExcelObject->createSheet(0);
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('General Overview');
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Title');
$writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
$writer->save('files/report.xls');
```

I think your issue might be not installing properly the bundle, or registering in your AppKernel.php. This should work just fine.

Comment: 1. First of all, How can I be notified when someone answered something to me? 

2. How can I run something like "php composer.phar update luiggioBundle? Because when I ran general composer update my project stopped working

Comment: 1. Issually there's a red number on top next to 'Stack Exchange' logo. (Also, there's an app for Android that linked to your account shows the popup on your phone when a new comment/answer to your question is received) 2. Your project shouldn't have stopped working, since everything you had on composer.json has to be valid and it should be the last composer.json you used when created/updated the project. See this answer on how to update single package http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739998/symfony2-how-to-update-a-single-library-with-composer-phar

Comment: I'll update to 2.0 like you with update liuggio/ExcelBundle command that you mentioned last post. I'll tell you what happen. Thank you. And we can speak spanish too :D

Comment: php composer.phar update /liuggio/ExcelBundle

Package "/liuggio/excelbundle" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Updating dependencies 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  P1
    - The requested package liuggio/excelbundle == 1.0.6.0 could not be found.
  P2
    - Installation request for symfony/icu == 1.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/
icu[v1.2.0].
    - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library
icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to
 have the extension providing it.

Comment: php composer.phar install instead. Also, please update your current composer.json on the question to see what we're dealing with.

Comment: That service is in luiggiobundle 1.0.6 but somehow the version my simfony installation has the master one. The code is referring to 1.0.6. How can I uninstall the luiggiobundle and install it again? Do you Have and Idea?

Comment: according to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680395/should-dependencies-be-deleted-from-disk-automatically-after-install-update-with running php composer.phar update removes the packages that were removed from your composer.json, please just to be sure, clear the cache and try again. Also, please verify all the requirements to run SF2.x are met (see http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/requirements.html). P2 is caused you don't have installed/enabled the INTL extension on PHP.

Comment: 1. I run php composer.phar self-update
2. Then php composer.phar update
while running I got this error http://prntscr.com/3lyydn

Comment: I solved the last commented by
1. deleting the vendors folder
2. with the composer updated, I executed php composer.phar update
3. I got this http://prntscr.com/3lz7x8
4. I think my code to generate the xcel refers to a previous phpexcel (1.0.7 or something like that cause I didn't develop this part)
5. Here is my code http://prntscr.com/3lz8kf
6. Here is my error in the web app http://prntscr.com/3lz93a

Comment: added example on how to write files

Comment: Thanks. What Im trying to do is generate the excel from an object and then create a table to show to the user and then this table its supposed to be exported to an excel file

Comment: I got some other requirements, hope I can start this as soon as posible. I'll let you know when I start this again. Thank you.

Comment: Hope can get on this by monday

Comment: I started to look at this again. With your example Im getting an error 

FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'project\nameBundle\Controller\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found

Comment: Did you used use PHPExcel_IOFactory; at the beginning?

Comment: At the end, I used the example that they have in github luiggiobundle documentation that is call something like "code for lazy developers" and with that example I was able to create, generate, add information and provide a link to download it.  Thank you for your help Splendonia, you provided me a lot of info that helped me to understand the bundle.